# Corda RPC Client unable to reconnect with corda node after the node restart

Tags: corda

I am trying to use the RPC connection management [code](https://docs.corda.net/head/clientrpc.html#connection-management) to enable auto-retry upon node failover. But I noticed that the client is unable to re connect with corda node after node restart. Below is my code:

```
class ConnectToCordaRPC(val nodeHostAndPort: NetworkHostAndPort, val 
   username: String, val password: String) {
    lateinit var rpcConnection: CordaRPCConnection
        private set
    lateinit var proxy: CordaRPCOps
        private set
    val logger = loggerFor<ConnectToCordaRPC>()

private fun establishConnectionWithRetry(): CordaRPCConnection? {
    val retryInterval = 5.seconds

    do {
        val connection = try {
            logger.info("Connecting to: $nodeHostAndPort")
            val cordaRPCClientConfiguration = CordaRPCClientConfiguration(retryInterval)
            val client = CordaRPCClient(
                    nodeHostAndPort,
                    cordaRPCClientConfiguration
            )
            val _connection = client.start(username, password)
            // Check connection is truly operational before returning it.
            val nodeInfo = _connection.proxy.nodeInfo()
            require(nodeInfo.legalIdentitiesAndCerts.isNotEmpty())
            _connection
        } catch(secEx: ActiveMQSecurityException) {
            // Happens when incorrect credentials provided - no point to retry connecting.
            throw secEx
        }
        catch(ex: RPCException) {
            // Deliberately not logging full stack trace as it will be full of internal stacktraces.
            logger.info("Exception upon establishing connection: " + ex.message)
            null
        }

        if(connection != null) {
            logger.info("Connection successfully established with: $nodeHostAndPort")
            return connection
        }
        // Could not connect this time round - pause before giving another try.
        Thread.sleep(retryInterval.toMillis())
    } while (connection == null)

    return null
}

fun performRpcReconnect() {
    rpcConnection = establishConnectionWithRetry()!!
    proxy = rpcConnection.proxy

    val (snapshot, updates) = proxy.vaultTrack(IOUState::class.java)

    //snapshot.states.forEach {}
    updates.toBlocking().subscribe { update ->
        update.produced.forEach { processState(it.state.data) }
    }

    val (stateMachineInfos, stateMachineUpdatesRaw) = proxy.stateMachinesFeed()

    val retryableStateMachineUpdatesSubscription: AtomicReference<Subscription?> = AtomicReference(null)
    val subscription: Subscription = stateMachineUpdatesRaw
            .startWith(stateMachineInfos.map { StateMachineUpdate.Added(it) })
            .subscribe({logger.info(it.id.toString())

                /* Client code here */ }, {
                logger.info("*********closing the connection*********")
                // Terminate subscription such that nothing gets past this point to downstream Observables.
                retryableStateMachineUpdatesSubscription.get()?.unsubscribe()
                // It is good idea to close connection to properly mark the end of it. During re-connect we will create a new
                // client and a new connection, so no going back to this one. Also the server might be down, so we are
                // force closing the connection to avoid propagation of notification to the server side.
                rpcConnection.forceClose()
                // Perform re-connect.
                performRpcReconnect()
            })

    retryableStateMachineUpdatesSubscription.set(subscription)
}
private fun processState(state: ContractState) {
    logger.info("state is "+ state.toString())

        }
    }
}

class EventListenerRPC {

    fun main(args: Array<String>) {

        require(System.getenv("CONFIG_RPC_HOST") != null) { "CONFIG_RPC_HOST env var was not set." }
        require(System.getenv("CONFIG_RPC_PORT") != null) { "CONFIG_RPC_PORT env var was not set." }
        require(System.getenv("CONFIG_RPC_USERNAME") != null) { "CONFIG_RPC_USERNAME env var was not set." }
        require(System.getenv("CONFIG_RPC_PASSWORD") != null) { "CONFIG_RPC_PASSWORD env var was not set." }


        val nodeIpAndPort = "${System.getenv(CORDA_VARS.CORDA_NODE_HOST)}:${System.getenv(CORDA_VARS.CORDA_NODE_RPC_PORT)}"
        val nodeAddress = NetworkHostAndPort.parse(nodeIpAndPort)

        val nodeUsername = System.getenv(CORDA_VARS.CORDA_USER_NAME)
        val nodePassword = System.getenv(CORDA_VARS.CORDA_USER_PASSWORD)
        val connectToCordaRPC = ConnectToCordaRPC(nodeAddress, nodeUsername, nodePassword)
        connectToCordaRPC.performRpcReconnect()
    }
}
```

Below is the log on client console:

```
    16:19:21.455 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] WARN org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client - AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119015: The connection was disconnected because of server shutdown [code=DISCONNECTED]
16:19:21.486 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl - Trying reconnection attempt 0/-1
16:19:21.486 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl - Trying to connect with connectorFactory = org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory@f09733f, connectorConfig=TransportConfiguration(name=913dad64-f4bb-11e8-844e-5cea1d41295b, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?host=192-168-249-61&port=10003&protocols=CORE,AMQP&useGlobalWorkerPool=true&RemotingThreads=-1
16:19:21.488 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector - Connector + NettyConnector [host=192.168.249.61, port=10003, httpEnabled=false, httpUpgradeEnabled=false, useServlet=false, servletPath=/messaging/ActiveMQServlet, sslEnabled=false, useNio=true] using nio
16:19:21.488 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector - Started Netty Connector version 4.1.27.Final
16:19:21.488 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector - Remote destination: /192.168.249.61:10003
16:19:22.729 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl - Connector towards NettyConnector [host=192.168.249.61, port=10003, httpEnabled=false, httpUpgradeEnabled=false, useServlet=false, servletPath=/messaging/ActiveMQServlet, sslEnabled=false, useNio=true] failed
16:19:27.732 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl - Trying reconnection attempt 1/-1
16:19:27.733 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl - Trying to connect with connectorFactory = org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory@f09733f, connectorConfig=TransportConfiguration(name=913dad64-f4bb-11e8-844e-5cea1d41295b, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?host=192-168-249-61&port=10003&protocols=CORE,AMQP&useGlobalWorkerPool=true&RemotingThreads=-1
16:19:27.736 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector - Connector + NettyConnector [host=192.168.249.61, port=10003, httpEnabled=false, httpUpgradeEnabled=false, useServlet=false, servletPath=/messaging/ActiveMQServlet, sslEnabled=false, useNio=true] using nio
16:19:27.736 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector - Started Netty Connector version 4.1.27.Final
16:19:27.736 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector - Remote destination: /192.168.249.61:10003
16:19:28.927 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl - Connector towards NettyConnector [host=192.168.249.61, port=10003, httpEnabled=false, httpUpgradeEnabled=false, useServlet=false, servletPath=/messaging/ActiveMQServlet, sslEnabled=false, useNio=true] failed
16:19:33.932 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl - Trying reconnection attempt 2/-1
16:19:33.932 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl - Trying to connect with connectorFactory = org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory@f09733f, connectorConfig=TransportConfiguration(name=913dad64-f4bb-11e8-844e-5cea1d41295b, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?host=192-168-249-61&port=10003&protocols=CORE,AMQP&useGlobalWorkerPool=true&RemotingThreads=-1
16:19:33.933 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector - Connector + NettyConnector [host=192.168.249.61, port=10003, httpEnabled=false, httpUpgradeEnabled=false, useServlet=false, servletPath=/messaging/ActiveMQServlet, sslEnabled=false, useNio=true] using nio
16:19:33.933 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector - Started Netty Connector version 4.1.27.Final
16:19:33.933 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector - Remote destination: /192.168.249.61:10003
16:19:35.128 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl - Connector towards NettyConnector [host=192.168.249.61, port=10003, httpEnabled=false, httpUpgradeEnabled=false, useServlet=false, servletPath=/messaging/ActiveMQServlet, sslEnabled=false, useNio=true] failed
16:19:40.132 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl - Trying reconnection attempt 3/-1
16:19:40.133 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl - Trying to connect with connectorFactory = org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory@f09733f, connectorConfig=TransportConfiguration(name=913dad64-f4bb-11e8-844e-5cea1d41295b, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?host=192-168-249-61&port=10003&protocols=CORE,AMQP&useGlobalWorkerPool=true&RemotingThreads=-1
16:19:40.136 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector - Connector + NettyConnector [host=192.168.249.61, port=10003, httpEnabled=false, httpUpgradeEnabled=false, useServlet=false, servletPath=/messaging/ActiveMQServlet, sslEnabled=false, useNio=true] using nio
16:19:40.136 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector - Started Netty Connector version 4.1.27.Final
16:19:40.136 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector - Remote destination: /192.168.249.61:10003
16:19:41.428 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl - Connector towards NettyConnector [host=192.168.249.61, port=10003, httpEnabled=false, httpUpgradeEnabled=false, useServlet=false, servletPath=/messaging/ActiveMQServlet, sslEnabled=false, useNio=true] failed
16:19:46.450 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl - Trying reconnection attempt 4/-1
16:19:46.456 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl - Trying to connect with connectorFactory = org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory@f09733f, connectorConfig=TransportConfiguration(name=913dad64-f4bb-11e8-844e-5cea1d41295b, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?host=192-168-249-61&port=10003&protocols=CORE,AMQP&useGlobalWorkerPool=true&RemotingThreads=-1
16:19:46.458 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector - Connector + NettyConnector [host=192.168.249.61, port=10003, httpEnabled=false, httpUpgradeEnabled=false, useServlet=false, servletPath=/messaging/ActiveMQServlet, sslEnabled=false, useNio=true] using nio
16:19:46.458 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector - Started Netty Connector version 4.1.27.Final
16:19:46.458 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector - Remote destination: /192.168.249.61:10003
16:19:46.620 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl - Reconnection successful
16:19:46.673 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client - AMQ214028: Couldnt reattach session {0}, performing as a failover operation now and recreating objects
16:19:46.791 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client - AMQ214028: Couldnt reattach session {0}, performing as a failover operation now and recreating objects
```

What could be the issue here? Is it because of the blocking code which subscribes for new state updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this with the Enterprise RPC client and node? If so, can you file a support ticket please? I'm not sure the open source RPC client has HA/failover support in it.

Comment: I am using Corda OS v3.2

Comment: But i assumed Artemis implicitly supports failover. So is the artemis failover being removed from OS version?

Comment: It's not being removed no. Artemis client library supports failover *between members of an Artemis cluster*. But when the broker is embedded in the node, two nodes = two different unrelated clusters, from Artemis' point of view. In Enterprise we've worked around this with some app level failover. Longer term the right way to go will be to set up an HA Artemis cluster, then an HA Corda cluster that uses it, and then "normal" Artemis failover should work. Support for separated Artemis is coming in Ent 4.

Comment: agree that Artemis supports failover between members. But i also thought that artemis client library will attempt to reconnect to the same broker automatically (not running in cluster mode) and the application need not write any extra code to try reconnecting. Also after reading this comment https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/client/rpc/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/client/rpc/internal/RPCClientProxyHandler.kt#L69 it looks like the failover is handled at artemis level?

Comment: Let me describe the problem i am facing:
i tried running the sample spring-boot app (from corda samples) and noticed that spring boot app can handle re-connection to the corda node automatically. so the above code is not required to do that and also i don't have to restart my app explicitly. BUT if I just run a basic RPCClient code which connects to the corda node and use vaultTrack RPC, the application has to be restarted explicitly because the `artemis disconnection` exception is not propagated back to the vaulTrack and hence cannot start tracking again.

Comment: it works well with spring-boot apps because when the api endpoints are invoked, the rpc calls are invoked explicitly.

Comment: Ah, reconnection of observables after a failover is a separate issue and I think not handled in Enterprise either. We have a lot of work to do on making failover totally transparent *with* the presence of registered observables - unfortunately at the moment re-observing things is up to the app itself.

Comment: hmm. but according to this doc https://docs.corda.net/head/clientrpc.html#connection-management it says that observer catches the exception upon disconnection and then application can re-try the connection. guess it should be updated